# Xcode Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code problem

Tags: flutter, xcode, crashlytics

I have an flutter project. We use xcode build in mac Xcode Version 14.2(14C18). I was able to build archieve before but after i tried a new version of flutter, I can't.  I changed my flutter version to 3.7.0 and then turn back to old version. I am able to build in iphones but archieve give **"Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code"** error. During the build, it tries for creating **dsym** but fails. Why that is happening? Would you help me to solve problem?

```
2023-07-19 21:02:16.980 upload-symbols[85744:6979333] Unable to get file attributes for dSYM file at path "/Users/user/Documents/MyApp/GitHub/Application/ios/DerivedData/Runner/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/App.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF"
```

I already update cocoapods.

On runner's firebase crashlytics input files; I have these lines;

```
"${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}/Contents/Resources/DWARF/${TARGET_NAME}"
"$(SRCROOT)/$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)"
```

Also I have this;

```
source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"
```